# Are prints to files logged somewhere?

Tags: logs, data-recovery, firefox, printing

So, I had a little accident the other day. I printed a file from a website to a PDF (using the Firefox print-to-file functionality). Unfortunately, I forgot to change the filename of the destination and wasn't properly paying attention. So I overwrote another PDF that I had printed via Firefox some time ago. I do not know what the content of that PDF was. But I remember that it was a potentially important document.

I realize that this has only happened because I made a whole serious of stupid mistakes. I did not immediately move said document to its proper location and rename it appropriately (instead I left it as `mozilla.pdf`, the default filename chosen by Firefox). Neither did I move it to the part of my home folder that is regularly backed up. And lastly, I could've prevented this if I had paid more attention and noticed the warning I presumably got when overwriting the file. Obviously, I need to be more careful about my personal data management.

But anyway, I would like to find out which document I lost. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 together with Firefox 80.0.1. I have already tried the following things:

1. Checking the CUPS job history (with `lpstat -W completed`), but this only gave me print jobs that were executed on actual printers, and I couldn't find a way to include prints to files.
2. Checking the Firefox history/logs. I ran a grep for the filename in the `~/.mozilla` folder, but didn't get anything useful.
3. Using `photorec` to recover lost PDF files, but it always froze after a few minutes, and didn't return any relevant file.
4. Checking my PDF viewer's (`evince`) history of recently opened documents for a telling thumbnail. Unfortunately, the old thumbnail to the file was no longer present. I also searched through `.cache/thumbnails` without success.

It would already be helpful to me to know the title of the document (the one that is displayed at the top of the window, rather than the filename), if it was somehow logged by the PDF viewer, or even just the URL that it originated from. I do realize this is a highly specific and very stupid problem. But the uncertainty is somewhat bothering me. It will most likely be nothing too important, if I cannot even remember what it was. But I was still wondering, whether there would be a way to find out more, and would be happy about any hint.

Comment: I wonder if your browser history lets you filter on "pdf" as part of the URL; that could narrow down which file(s) you saved previously. (This assumes that the previous file started as a PDF; if you printed some other filetype to pdf, it's no help)

Comment: Maybe the CUPS system logs in `/var/log/cups`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Unfortunately, it was not a PDF. I just save those via download.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks for the hint. I have looked there, but couldn't find anything useful. I suppose, it's time to simply let it go.